# Django CSV file is saved with quotation marks. How can I remove them?

Tags: python, django, csv

So my CSV file is saved with quotation marks like this:

"First name", "Last name", "Email", "Status", "Type", "Company name"

"Bugs", "Bunny", "bbb@bugsbb.com", "Active", "IT", "carrot"

Is there a way to remove those quotation marks?

Here is my code:

```
response = HttpResponse(content_type='text/csv')
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="file.csv"'

members = Member.objects.all().filter(......)
csv_data = [(str('First name'), str('Last name'), str('Email'), str('Status'), str('Type'), str('Company name'))]
for member in members:
    current_company = member.current_company.name if member.current_company else None
    csv_data.append(
        [
            str(member.first_name),
            str(member.last_name),
            str(member.email),
            str(member.member_Status),
            str(member.member_type),
            str(current_company)
        ])
t = loader.get_template('export_members.txt')
c = Context({'data': csv_data})
response.write(t.render(c))

return response
```

I also tried to turn the whole csv_data into binary... but it didn't work.

Comment: Paste your export_members.txt?

Comment: csv is valid with these quotations, are you sure you need to remove them?

Comment: Yes.. you right.. and this is the part I want to kill myself for asking such an idiotic question... I had those quotation marks in the txt file.

Answer (score 2):

Here you can read about outputting CSV with django https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/outputting-csv/

In that way you can use http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.writer with `quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE`